# Android XML Parser

Tags: android, xml, nsxmlparser

Does anyone know of an XML parser similar the [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Open Source [FeedGoal](http://code.google.com/p/feedgoal/) that comes with the source to parse RSS/Atom feed.

Alternatively, check this [IBM Article on XML Parsing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html). It has examples on parsing the RSS feed that you could probably use.